# Enter Route without adding it to browser history?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I have a Route who's only job is to display an iframe.

The path changes in the iframe are added to the browser history which allows a user to go back and forward.

Is it possible to enter the Route that contains this iframe without adding to history?

I am thinking something like:

```
<Route component={MyComponent} onEnter={location.history.pop}>
```

I am using React Router v4